# How to reload Flutter data when I press "back button"?

Tags: flutter

I have this kind of flow:

1. one page named "Posts". In this page you can click edit button on one of the posts and get redirected to
2. "Post Page". Here you can click edit and see the 3rd page "Edit Post" page
3. "Edit Post" page. Now I can modify the page here and click "back button" which does `navigator.of(context).pop();` and when I go back to page 1 want to refetch the list of posts.

My very simplified incomplete code looks like:

Posts page

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _initFuture();
}

_initFuture() {
  _future = _postsService.getUserPosts();
}

return FutureBuilder(
      future: _future,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        ...it builds the posts and on edit click navigates to editPost page
        Navigator.push(context, PostPage)
}
```

`PostPage` shows the single post and has a pen edit button. On click it does

```
 onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      Navigator.push(
                          context, EditPostPage.route(postId: widget.postId));
                    },
```

`EditPost` page has a scaffold, it can modify the post and on click button does "navigator.of(context).pop()"

Another question which achieves same result that I want is:
How can I actually trigger the initState or some re-render when the page is shown as a result of a "back" button brought back from the pages stack. Ex: One page does navigator.of(context).pop() and ThePage is shown. Is there any way for "ThePage" to know this and make again one api call instead of using the pre-existing state data

Answer (score 0):

Pass a Function from your "Post" to your "PostPage". In this function you call setState with the new data.

For this you have to declare a variable of type Function inside your PostPage.

```
Function onResultCallback;
```

Accept a Function inside your PostPage constructor:

```
PostPage(this.onResultCallback);
```

If you navigate to PostPage, pass a Function which accepts your new data or whatever you want and call setState to refresh the ui:

```
Navigator.push(context, PostPage(
(dynamic newData){
setState(() { myData = newData; });
})
```

Just await the Navigator.push, make your function async for the await keyword.

It should look like this:

```
var result = await Navigator.push(context, EditPostPage.route(postId: widget.postId));
```

Now call the callback function after you retrieved the new data.

```
this.onResultCallback(result).call();
```

This calls the setState function in "Posts" and updates your ui with the new data.

Since you said in your question "and when I go back to page 1 want to refetch the list of posts." you can also just call

```
_postsService.getUserPosts();
```

inside your onResultCallback, since that seems to fetch the posts for you. Then you don't have to pass a parameter to the function, but I'll leave it in there in case you want to pass data to the parent widget.

Small tip: Using this example, you see how stupid this can be when you want to update a parent from a child. Now imagine this was even more deeply nested, then you would have to pass the callback even deeper into your widgets.

So it's worth looking at state management solutions like Provider, Riverpod, BLoC or similar, depending on how complex the project is.

Comment: I don't open the page directly. Page1->Page2->Page3 Page1 does not know if Page 3 or Page4 opens it needs always to reset state

Comment: Ah ok, so you want to update Page1 after you go back from Page3 to Page2? If yes, see my edited answer.